# How do I get the Axis size, in pixels, from a LiveCharts Axis in order to determine a custom number of Separator steps on the axis?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, livecharts

I am using the WinForms version of [LiveCharts](https://lvcharts.net/) to plot a series of data, as a LineSeries, in my .NET application. I would like to be able to adjust the number of 'ticks' shown on the X axis depending on the length of the axis in pixels. So far, I haven't been able to determine what the length of the axis actually is. On inspection at runtime, the `Axis` object has a `Height` and a `Width` of `NaN` so my method fails to calculate a correct number of ticks (or steps).

So, my question is, how do I get the correct size of the `Axis` object, as shown on screen, in pixels?

My code so far:

Form method calling `Chart` class methods to get number of ticks based on a desired pixel spacing and the set the tick spacing on the axis:

```
private static void UpdateChainageTickSpacing()
{
    Axis chainageAxis = Chart.GetAxisByName(AxisOrientation.X, "Chainage");
    int numTicks = Chart.GetNumTicksByPixelSpacing(chainageAxis, 40);
    Chart.SetTickSpacing(chainageAxis, numTicks, 0);
}
```

In `Chart` class:

```
public static void SetTickSpacing(Axis axis, int numTicks, int precision)
{
    double maxValue = double.MinValue;
    double minValue = double.MaxValue;

    foreach (Series series in AllSeries)
    {
        maxValue = Math.Max(GetMaxValue(series, GetAxisOrientation(axis)), maxValue);
        minValue = Math.Min(GetMinValue(series, GetAxisOrientation(axis)), minValue);
    }

    double range = maxValue - minValue;
    double spacing = range / numTicks;
    spacing = Math.Round(spacing / 10, precision) * 10;
    axis.Separator.Step = spacing;
}

public static int GetNumTicksByPixelSpacing(Axis axis, int pixelSpacing)
{
    double pixelSize;

    if (GetAxisOrientation(axis) == AxisOrientation.X)
    {
        int index = GetAxisIndexByName(GetAxisCollection(AxisOrientation.X), axis.Name);
        pixelSize = cartesianChart.AxisX[index].Width;   // this returns NaN
    }
    else
    {
        int index = GetAxisIndexByName(GetAxisCollection(AxisOrientation.Y), axis.Name);
        pixelSize = cartesianChart.AxisY[index].Height;   // this returns NaN
    }

    return (int)Math.Round(pixelSize / pixelSpacing);
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the right way. The chart elements are all relative to the axis values. You should rather watch the axis value range/zoom to determine the number of sections...

Comment: I am doing this in order to deal with form resizing and ensure that an appropriate number of separator steps are shown based on the width of the chart control itself. I'll have a play with the canvas elements as described in your answer below and see how that works as I don't think using the value range and/or zoom would provide what I need.

Comment: Maybe you can set the chart to fixed size and wrap it into a ScrollViewer. In order to provide more details or higher resolution/precision, the user should use zooming instead of resizing the form. If you change the number of separators on the same value range, then a step becomes a new value. If axis has a range of 100 and you have 10 steps then I know each bar increments by 10. This helps me to get a raw understanding for the graph.

Comment: Now when I double the size of the window you double the number of bars, each bar now increments by 5 as the range remains the same (100). This can be confusing. Unless I explicitly change the scale of the grid I'd expect the weight of the separators to be always the same (in this case 10). I think the point is that those separators relate to the axis values and not the rendered pixel length of the axis element. You just give it a new and unexpected meaning. But I think you know what you want.

Comment: Sure, I get what you mean. I think, for my purposes, it's preferable to increase the number of separators on the X axis as the width of the chart increases but I fully get what you mean. Thanks for the help with the answer below, it got it to where it needed to be.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that your question targets Winforms, while my answer targets WPF (the view part). But from your last comment I feel that it doesn't confuse you. I mean the  solution is plain C# and platform independent. You only need to adjust the events I think. Sorry for this one.

Comment: No problem, I changed the question as I realised your answer was targeting WPF and I hadn't specified which. The WinForms version of CartesianChart refers back to the WPF version using the `Base` property, so easy enough to get the plot canvas and the dimensions I needed. Thanks again for your help, this had me stumped for a while!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart has two `Canvas` elements: the parent `Canvas` contains chart elements like the legends, sections etc. and another child `Canvas` as the actual plot area to host the plotted graph.

The axis lengths (x and y) are equal to the plot area's dimensions (width and height).

You can access the plot canvas by referencing the parent `Canvas` via the `CartesianChart.Content` property:

You need to wait until all elements have been added to the plot canvas to get it's final size.

The chart itself doesn't expose an event that notifies when the content layout has completed. So you have to listen to the `UIElement.LayoutUpdated` event of the plot canvas.

To achieve this, you need to subscribe to the `Canvas.LayoutUpdated` event from either a `Window.ContentRendered` or `Window.Loaded` event handler. Since you want to ignore as many redundant layout updates as possible, the `Window.ContentRendered` event, which is raised last, is the best in this scenario.

`UIElement.LayoutUpdated` is raised during every layout pass like resize or `Canvas.Children` collection manipulation like add/move/remove a child element, which is quite often and therefore needs some optimization to reduce redundant re-calculations.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <CartesianChart x:Name="Chart" />
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow: Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    
    this.ContentRendered += OnContentRendered;
  }

  private void OnContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    this.ContentRendered -= OnContentRendered;

    var canvas = this.Chart.Content as Canvas;
    var plotCanvas = canvas.Children.OfType<Canvas>().FirstOrDefault();
    plotCanvas.LayoutUpdated += GetAxisXLengthOnLayoutUpdated;
  }

  // Will be called very often 
  // (on every layout pass of the Canvas sender like on resize or add/move/remove child)
  private void GetAxisXLengthOnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    var plotCanvas = sender as Canvas;

    // If this is a one time operation, unsubscribe from LayoutUpdated event
    plotCanvas.LayoutUpdated -= GetAxisXLengthOnLayoutUpdated;

    // The length of the x-axis is equal to the final width of the plot area
    var actualAxisXLength = plotCanvas.ActualWidth;
  }
}
```